# Display text from listbox array into a textbox

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I am trying to display the text that is stored in my listbox array into my text box my current code has no errors but nothing is being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

```
private void genreTitleTextBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Adding first genre title
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\James Dunn\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 2\Assignment 2\MyJukeBox\bin\Debug\Media\Genre.txt");
        for (int l = 1; l < lines.Length; l++)
        {
            mediaLibrary[0].Items.Add(lines[l]);
            if (l == 4)
                break;
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(mediaLibrary[0].ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < mediaLibrary.Length; i++)
            builder.Append(", ").Append(mediaLibrary[NumberofGenre]);
        genreTitleTextBox.Text = builder.ToString();
    }
```

My text file is laid out like this

```
3
2
Other
Big Bad John (1961) - Jimmy Dean.mp3
My Ding A Ling - Chuck Berry.mp3
2
Rap
2pac-ghost.mp3
B.I.G-Spit Your Game.mp3
1
Rock
Linkin park-Numb.mp3
```

I need to display the first genre which is line number 3 Other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really? Nothing is displayed? This line seems to assume that you can get the text contents of a ListBox with the TosTring Method:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(mediaLibrary[0].ToString());
```

But it will instead add the classname and some other information about the ListBox into the StringBuilder.

If you want to get at the **content** you will have to loop over the Items and add them like this:

```
foreach(object o in (mediaLibrary[0].Items) builder.AppendLine(o.ToString());
```

As for more errors.. first correct this one, then report back..

Comment: I have done this and it still doesn't display anything

Comment: Are you looking at things with the debugger? If not, that is the first thing you are doing wrong.. Also: where does the event come from? TextBoxes don't usually have a Load event?!

Comment: ah i think thats where i might be going wrong i typed in the event